# In place update columns of a matrix

Tags: memory, julia

I'm trying to optimize the speed and allocation of this loop

```
function loop(n,k)
    m = rand(10,n)
    r = rand(10,1)
    for j in 1:k
        for i in 2:size(m,2)
            @inbounds m[:,i-1] = m[:,i] + rand!(r)
        end
    end
end
```

The memory allocation is quite big: `@time loop(10000,30)` has an allocation of 599.94k, increasing in `k`. I think there are two contributing factors: (1) allocation of `m[:,i]` and (2) allocation of `m[:,i-1]`. I'm hoping that `@inbounds` can help, but it doesn't. Removing `@inbounds` doesn't help with the allocation.

Is there a way to reduce allocations? I'm really not creating any new objects, so it should be invariant to `k`. I tried to replace `@inbounds` with `@view` but it didn't even run. I don't think I can use `broadcast!` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use views as they do not materialize, use broadcasting.

```
function loop2(n,k)
           m = rand(10,n)
           for j in 1:k
               for i in 2:size(m,2)
                   @inbounds m[:,i-1] .= @view(m[:,i]) .+ rand(10)
               end
           end
       end
```

The new version is 3x faster and uses 3.5x less allocations and 40% of memory:

```
julia> @btime loop(1000,1000)
  227.918 ms (3485003 allocations: 327.64 MiB)

julia> @btime loop2(1000,1000)
  75.154 ms (999002 allocations: 152.51 MiB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Prezemyslaw points out the main issues, but I see a further benefit from combining his ideas with your original idea of preallocating `r` and then using in place `rand!`:

```
julia> using Random

julia> function loop3(n,k)
           m = rand(10,n)
           r = rand(10)
           for j in 1:k
               for i in 2:size(m,2)
                   @inbounds m[:,i-1] .= @view(m[:,i]) .+ rand!(r) 
               end
           end
       end
loop3 (generic function with 1 method
```

Which gives:

```
julia> @btime loop(1_000, 1_000)
  266.851 ms (3485003 allocations: 327.64 MiB)

julia> @btime loop2(1_000, 1_000)
  101.003 ms (999002 allocations: 152.51 MiB)

julia> @btime loop3(1_000, 1_000)
  61.447 ms (3 allocations: 78.36 KiB)
```

which is basically now just the allocation of `m` and `r`:

```
julia> @btime begin
           rand(10, 1_000); rand(10)
       end
  15.881 μs (3 allocations: 78.36 KiB)
```

Comment: If the initial values of `r` are not used for anything even better could be `r = Vector{Float64}(undef,10)`

Comment: You can also write `view(m, :,i) .+ rand.() `, which will call `rand` while broadcasting, instead of before. This avoids needing `r`, although it's not quicker (for me).